# How can I get better quality street view image by using street view image API?

Tags: google-maps-static-api

I knew that "street view image API" for business provides "2048x2048" size of street view image.

However, I think above method cannot give me better quality of street view images although size might affect some improvement of quality of the street view images.

Do you know any better method to improve quality(or high resolution) of street view images by using "street view image API" ?

thanks in advance for everyone's comments.

Answer (score 0):

While some of the 2048^2 images might provide better quality of images (with the higher resolution and all), you should keep in mind that the photoquality relies on camera type, camera settings, weather conditions, compression, etc. etc. a lot of factors.

Improving an image is *somewhat* possible but you'd have to use programs like photoshop, and even then you wouldn't get an image that is truly of better quality, just manipulated to look better. Just improving by throwing a bool to true seems rather impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get higher-quality images from the business API, but you'll have to pay and tell Google what you're doing.